# Installing a C++ service using batch file exception

Tags: c++, windows, batch-file, service, installation

I have a C++ service program which was developed in visual studio on another machine and I am trying to install the service using a Batch file.
The exception I get can be seen in the image alongside the code within the Batch file.
(refer to image 2)

From what I have found online it seems like the exception is being caused due to a compatibility issue as the program was developed using a 64-bit OS and I am trying to install the service on a 32-bit.

Also when I go to the configuration manager x86 does not appear on the drop down list, only Itanium, Win32 and x64.
(refer to image 1)

How can I resolve this error and install the service?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Screenshots:

[image: Missing x86 option]
[image: Batch file and Exception]
[image: Dependency Walker results]

Comment: win32 = x86 ... And use dependency walker to figure out which dependency is missing

Comment: The fact that you *developed* the application on a 64-bit OS is irrelevant. What matters is whether you built it as a 64-bit or a 32-bit program (check your project settings). If it is a 64-bit program, then you cannot run it on a 32-bit version of Windows. You must recompile it as 32-bit prior to deployment.

Comment: Also, why are you installing .NET for a C++ program? Perhaps you meant C++/CLI?

Comment: @JBentley The project is currently targeted towards Win32 and as I mentioned x86 doesn't appear as an option in the configuration manager.
I am new to both C++ and using Batch files, I found the code for the Batch file online and tweaked it so that it would work with my service.

Comment: @stijn I have included the results of the dependency walker above.